# Best hardware-software application for sending a voltage based on output from a report

Tags: arduino, power-control, plc

I'm looking for some direction here to start. If this is not the right forum, please direct me to the right one.

I have a piece of equipment that runs a process and is continuously sending data to a database. I have a python script that parses the data and will send a report when one of the parameters are outside a set limit.
The equipment has a functionality where the process can be aborted when a voltage is applied to a PCB board.

I am looking for a way to get the report to trigger an abort on the equipment.
My first thought is to get an Arduino like board to interface between python and the voltage board on the equipment. Whenever the python script encounters a limit violation, it sends a command to the Arduino board which then triggers a voltage to the equipment to abort.

But i was wondering if there are any off the shelf hardware that would interface with python that achieves this.
Any advice (in your experience as automation engineers/developers) to send me down a path to research will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: You can't get much simpler than an Arduino and some code to talk to it over COM. Python has plenty of modules for talking to serial devices. I think using any other "product" for this is going to bring along a lot of features or API overhead that you don't need. For instance, there are probably "ready to use" devices you can buy that have a network interface and can be told to toggle electrical switches by Modbus or something, but they will do a whole lot more and cost a lot more.

Comment: There is dedicated Arduino site: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: National Instruments has many "ready made" devices that I have used for similar projects, but I agree with Romen, it will add a lot more cost and overhead compared to Arduino.